# How to play a video in fullscreen mode and exit fullscreen mode in Android WebView?

Tags: android, video, webview, fullscreen

I know this is an old question and it was asked many times. But I tried many solutions they don't work with me.

I tested it in my Huawei 6P and Samsung S7, Nexus 5, 
the video(https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/M68lNfqmTNk?rel=0&rel=0&showinfo=0) in WebView doesn't work as expected(it worked last year.). 
When I click the fullscreen button,  "onShowCustomView" and "onHideCustomView" are invoked continuously. So I can see the video flashed(non-fullscreen  -> full-screen -> non-fullscreen). 
Sometimes if I am lucky, the video goes full-screen mode, but if press full-screen button to exit fullscreen mode, the button doesn't work at all.

I wrote a demo in [GitHub](https://github.com/zhihuitang/VideoTest), hope anyone can help me. thanks.

Here is the code

Init Webview:

```
    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

MyWebChromeClient:

```
 public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        Log.d("youtube", "onShowCustomView");
        // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }
        mContentView = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCustomViewContainer = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
        mCustomViewContainer.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
        mCustomViewContainer.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
        view.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
        mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
        mCustomView = view;
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        Log.d("youtube", "onHideCustomView");
        if (mCustomView == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            // Show the content view.
            mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setContentView(mContentView);
        }
    }

}
```

I did set  android:hardwareAccelerated in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842869/how-to-fullscreen-youtube-video-in-webview please refer this hope this help!!!

Comment: thanks. I tried it doesn't work with me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796661/android-webview-app-wont-let-video-player-go-full-screen/16199649#16199649 have you seen this?

Comment: yes, I cloned the repo to my local it didn't work with me. Thanks @Kushan2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load youtube video in webview, you must use iframe instead, 
ex:

```
<iframe width="300" height=".." src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M68lNfqmTNk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and load html text to the webview, something like this: `<html><body> <iframe width="330" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M68lNfqmTNk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>....`

Comment: Good point!. I added a local html file in my assets folder. Now seems the "fullscreen" button works. But sometimes the whole screen is black after fullscreen. I updated the demo code in github

Comment: I checked your code, first t think you must delete the play video button, it's useless because after load the url to the webview the user has to click again to play the video,  so I think it's better to load it in onCreate , and Try youtube api for playing youtube videos, it's better then using webview

Answer (score 0):

i think there are many answers already predefined for this questions 
but i think you need to just check this answer once [markparnelllink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763483/android-webview-with-an-embedded-youtube-video-full-screen-button-freezes-video/15127046#15127046)

in that link Mark defined solution in very detailed

Comment: You can see, that my code of the Demo is from markparnelllink. Doesn't work with my youtube video. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

add this code in your webview.
`webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");`